# Link from Object as src to img tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to pass information (link) form Object, and give it as the src to image. Somehow  tag doesn't see it. Even though it console log proper link and the link is working.

Object

```
setup() {

const state = reactive({
  flashcardObject: {
  linkToGraphic: 'https://static.fajnyzwierzak.pl/media/uploads/media_image/auto/entry-content/785/mobile/dog-niemiecki.jpg'}
})


 return{
  state
 }
}
```

Where is the bug

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="ViewFlashcards">
      <div class="image_div">
        <img class="picture" src="{{state.flashcardObject.linkToGraphic}}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### Thank you for your help!

Comment: Isnt it `:src="state....."`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), like so:

```
<img v-bind:src="state.flashcardObject.linkToGraphic" class="picture"/>
```

**Full code:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="ViewFlashcards">
      <div class="image_div">
        <img class="picture" v-bind:src="state.flashcardObject.linkToGraphic"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`v-bind` allows you to bind an (HTML) attribute to a data property or just some JS code. In this case you just pass along your image URL to the `src` attribute of the `<image>`.

Note that mustache syntax, `{{ something }}`, does not work in HTML attributes; it only will work within elements, like `<p>{{ something }}</p>`.

Also, note that instead of `v-bind:attribute`, you can omit the `v-bind` part and just keep the colon, like so: `:attribute`. This makes it easier to bind attributes.

For more info and examples [see the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Answer (score 1):

You should require it and use `:` to bind the image src to the required path if the image is stored in the app :

```
<img class="picture" :src="require(state.flashcardObject.linkToGraphic)"/>
```

or :

```
  <img class="picture" :src="state.flashcardObject.linkToGraphic"/>
```

if the image is hosted online.